# Shouldn't the begin() and end() functions be member functions of the template class Vector?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, auto

[In page 82 of the draft of Chapter 3 : A Tour of C++: Abstraction Mechanisms](http://isocpp.org/images/uploads/3-Tour-Abstr.pdf) the author writes:

> If we also want to use the range-for loop for our **Vector**, we must
>   deﬁne suitable **begin()** and **end()** functions:

```
template<typename T>
T∗ begin(Vector<T>& x)
{
    return &x[0]; // pointer to ﬁrst element
}

template<typename T>
T∗ end(Vector<T>& x)
{
    return x.begin()+x.size(); // pointer to one-past-last element
}
```

Given those, we can write:

```
void f2(const Vector<string>& vs) // Vector of some strings
{
    for (auto s : vs)
        cout << s << ’\n’;
}
```

Notice that the class template **Vector** is defined in page 81 of the draft.

Comment: The range based loop would also work if you defined `begin()` and `end()` as member functions.

Comment: @juanchopanza But they are not member functions.

Comment: What I mean is, you have the option of using member functions. Either way, the range based loop will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For range-based for to work, the compiler needs to find a suitable function to get the iterators.

- If the type used is a class, it'll first look for member functions `begin` and `end` in the scope of that class.
- If the type is not a class or the are no such member functions, it looks them up by [Argument Dependent Lookup.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup)

This is the reason range-based for works on C-arrays. Obviously, arrays can't have member functions, so standard library provides two functions defined similarly to this:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
T* begin( T(&array)[N] )
{
    return array;
}
```

and similarly for `end`.

To answer your question from the title: they *can* be, but it's not a neccesity. You can define free functions in the same namespace as your class and they'll be found.

Comment: Actually arrays are treated as a special case. Not great to paste Standard quotes into comments, but see 6.5.4 The range-based `for` statement: `"if _RangeT is an array type, begin-expr and end-expr are __range and __range + __bound, respectively, where __bound is the array bound."`

Comment: @BoBTFish I believe this is subject to as-if rule. `begin-expr` needs to behave as if it was `__range`, but it's up to compiler/library how it achieves this. libstdc++, for example, does it [they way I wrote.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/libstdc++/api/a01014.html)

Comment: "this is probably an implementation detail." Those overloads are required to exist. I don't think your link goes any way to showing that they are used in range-based-`for` for arrays by gcc. In fact, I see no reason not to think that range-based-`for` is required to work on arrays in a freestanding implementation, and looking at `17.6.1.3 Freestanding implementations` the `<iterators>` header is not required in that case. Does gcc support compiling for embedded chips and such without the library? I have no idea about such things.

Comment: @BoBTFish You're right, these functions are required. And I don't know that either. That could be a good SO question, perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

If it is not an array or a container with `.begin()` and `.end()` it will look up by [Argument dependent name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup).

It is said [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj203382.aspx) :

> Keep in mind these facts about range-based for:
>
> - Automatically recognizes arrays.
> - Recognizes containers that have .begin() and .end().
> - **Uses argument-dependent lookup begin() and end() for anything else.**

Answer (score 2):

In such a range based for:

```
for ( for-range-declaration : expression ) statement
```

the standard says that the compiler looks for either members (`(expression).begin()`, `(expression).end()`) or free functions (`begin((expression))`, `end((expression))`) if expression is of class type.

Therefore **you can either provide member functions OR free functions** (which need to be in scope for argument dependant lookup).

> #### C++11, § 6.5.4 [stmt.ranged]

This is what a ranged-based for does according to the standard:

```
for ( for-range-declaration : expression ) statement

range-init = ( expression )

{
  auto && __range = range-init;
  for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
    __end = end-expr;
    __begin != __end;
    ++__begin ) 
  {
    for-range-declaration = *__begin;
    statement
  }
}
```

The `begin-expr` and `end-expr` are described as:

> - if **`_RangeT`** is an array type, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are **_*range*** and **_range + _*bound***, respectively, where **_bound** is the array bound. If **_RangeT** is an array of unknown size or an array of incomplete type, the program is ill-formed;
> - if **`_RangeT`** is a class type, the unqualified-ids begin and end are looked up in the scope of class _RangeT as if by class member access lookup (3.4.5), and if either (or both) finds at least one declaration, beginexpr and end-expr are __range.begin() and __range.end(), respectively;
> - otherwise, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are **`begin(__range)`** and **`end(__range)`**, respectively, where **`begin`** and **`end`** are looked up with argument-dependent lookup (3.4.2). For the purposes of this name lookup, namespace std is an associated namespace.

Comment: So if `__range.begin()` is a member but both `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)` exist as free functions found via ADL, it will look for `__range.end()` and break?

Comment: @BenVoigt I guess you're right since the standard says `if [...] finds at least one declaration [...]`. It suggests the behaviour you describe.